# What is thymeleaf? And what are the advantages of using thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Why do we need thymeleaf. How it is helpful for the developers? I have seen an example where user name is fetched using a simple code by the author in w3schools.com like below.

```
**<form:inputText name="userName" value="${user.name}" />**
```

Also, the same author from w3schools try to teach how we can fetch the user name using thymeleaf as below.

```
**<input type="text" name="userName" value="James Carrot" th:value="${user.name}" />**
```

But my question is why do we need thymeleaf? It simply increasing code size. Someone please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Thymeleaf is a template engine. Who will populate ${user.name} in the first example?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli What do you mean by template engine...As we are using bootstrap for designing and HTML to create web pages

Comment: what is the first line? What framework/library is providing the value?

Comment: It is an expression tag through which we can fetch pojo values through controller

Comment: If I'm wrong please correct me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of a solution is thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806245/what-kind-of-a-solution-is-thymeleaf)

Comment: but what framework is doing this?$

Comment: @andrewjames Thank you. Yeah much similar

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it's called expression language...we use such expressions even in angular. $ fetches the values whatever which is inside {}

Comment: Yes I understand but WHO is doing that? Thymleaf is template engine that USES an expression langauge

Comment: Please read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-template-engines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thymeleafe is a template engine like JSP. It makes developer work easy by designing application templates effectively. It composes many features which make a developer's life easy.

For more information see "[Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html)".

Also, from Stackoverflow "[What kind of a solution is thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806245/what-kind-of-a-solution-is-thymeleaf)".

Also, you will find many questions for the beginner's level.

Do not hesitate to ask questions. Keep digging.